# Year Quarter PHP / Javascript pattern

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I need pattern for a quarter of a year, for example 1/2015 -> first quarter of the 2015. 4/2015 -> fourth quarter of the year. I need to validate given value for being a quarter. How I can achieve that in javascript or php ? I guess that in PHP preg_match function is good way to go but I have difficulties with creating correct pattern...

Comment: No,  I want to validate if a given string is in the correct format -> 1/2015 -> correct, 12/2015 -> incorrect, 8sdsa -> incorrect etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the range of years that you'd like to support.

Assuming anything between quarter 1/1000 and 4/2999 should be accepted then the regular expression you want to use is

```
/^[1234]\/[12]\d{3}$/
```

For example this JavaScript function will test for valid quarters

```
function is_quarter(text) {
  return text.match(/^[1234]\/[12]\d{3}$/) != null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mm. Not 100% sure I understand, but how about this?

```php
function is_quarter($string) {
    $parts = explode('/', $string);

    if(count($parts) == 2) {
        $quarter = (int) $parts[0];

        return $quarter >= 1 && $quarter <= 4;
    }

    return false;
}
```

```javascript
function isQuarter(string) {
    var parts = string.split('/');

    if(parts.length == 2) {
        var quarter = parseInt(parts[0]);

        return quarter >= 1 && quarter <= 4;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I've added a JS version as well. Beware: Both are untested.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function Check(){
  var v = document.getElementById("Quarter").value;
  alert(/^[1-4]\/\d{4}$/.test(v));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="Quarter" />
<input type="button" value="Check" onclick="Check();" />
```